# How Does Rogue's Reliable Talent Work?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

So I'm making a Bard Rogue as a potential character for a D&D group I'm joining, and I was looking at Rogue at higher levels (debating between High Bard with Low Rogue or Low Bard with High Rogue) when I came across Reliable Talent PHB 96. It states

> ... Whenever you make an ability check that lets you add your proficiency bonus, you can treat a d20 roll of 9 or lower as a ten.

So here's the question. It specifically states "roll" *not* "result" which begs the question of is this ability referring to the end result being a 9 or lower (Including modifiers), OR the d20 roll without modifiers being a 9 or lower.

I personally think it is the roll before modifiers, since at level 11 you have a +4 Proficiency Bonus, but figured I'd ask here.

Comment: You might want to put your exact question in the title for better results.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's the roll before modifiers.

D&D 5th edition is very specific about its terminology. When it says a d20 roll, it means a d20 roll, not a result or a check.

> When a D&D rule refers to rolling a number on a die, the rule means the number on the die. For example, rolling a 9 on a d20 means the number 9 on the die. In contrast, an ability check, a saving throw, or an attack roll includes the die roll and any relevant modifiers.
>   [Tweet from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/983517035689734145)

Effectively, this ability means that you can never roll below 10 on the d20. Instead of a range of 1-20, your range is now 10-20. Hence "reliable" - you can be certain of at least average results every time.

Comment: heavily weighted to the 10 though.

Comment: Jeremy Crawford confirms this interpretation [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/05/11/can-you-explain-the-relationship-of-the-rogues-reliable-talent-and-expertise/) (specifically [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/983517035689734145)): "When a D&D rule refers to rolling a number on a die, the rule means the number on the die. For example, rolling a 9 on a d20 means the number 9 on the die. In contrast, an ability check, a saving throw, or an attack roll includes the die roll and any relevant modifiers."

Comment: @MichaelGorman To add to that, here is the statistical output that the Rogue can expect: An average of 12.5, with 50% chance of 10 and then 5% everything above 10. https://anydice.com/program/fec0 The answered may or may not want to include that in their answer.